# What is the alternative in HarmonyOS for valueAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners() in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In Android while finishing an animation on valueAnimator, we do the following:

```java
void end() { 
    // Code for final state of the animation
    valueAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners(); 
}
```

What is the alternative for the above code snippet in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 0):

The team confirmed that there is currently no alternative of the `removeAllUpdateListeners()` in HarmonyOS .

You may refer to the Java UI animation, see [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-animation-0000000000580278).